# Screen take few seconds to open while using gridview xhdpi images

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I am new in android so I am trying to show the images size more than 50 Xhdpi in gridview but while doing this when I execute my program it makes screen hold for sometime and then execute.

Can any one tell the reason why it is taking time.

Here is my code:

```
mGv_detail = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    init();

    key_value = getIntent().getIntExtra("values", 0);

    switch (key_value) {
    case 0:

        mGv_detail.setAdapter(new DetailAdapter(this, first_images));

        break;


@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = view;
    RecordHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (v == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.imagev = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imag_v);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        Log.e("Position", "" + position);
        holder = (RecordHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(v.getResources(),
            items.get(position));
    holder.imagev.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
    // holder.imagev.setImageResource(items.get(position));
    holder.imagev.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    holder.imagev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Christmas.class);
            i.putExtra("clickposition", position);
            Log.e("postiont clicked", position+"");
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    return v;

}

static class RecordHolder {

    ImageView imagev;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of images. It will lag, even for local image files.

You should use a tool like "Universal Image Loader" -

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/ImageLoader.java

Basically, given that many images, it will take a few moments. I have a GridView with about that many images, and using Universal Image Loader it takes about 3 or 4 seconds even on a fast, new device. However, it will display immediately and you can watch the grid fill with images and it isn't a big deal if you use a tool. If you don't, you really feel the lag.

Answer (score 0):

Your getView method which is resposible for displaying the cells in your GridView is loading your bitmaps into memory synchronously.  The delay is very natural given this order of events.  If you use one of the many image loading libraries available for Android, this work can be quite easily offloaded to a background thread and called back when ready.  My personal favorite is Picasso.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

You can add Picasso as a jar file or via gradle, and then image loading would look something like this:

```
int resId = images.get(position);
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(resId).into(holder.imagev);
```